# Remove trailing "-" characters from a string in VB6

Tags: string, vb6

I need to remove trailing "-" characters from a string in VB6. How can i achieve this? Any help or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but it will execute relatively slowly. I would think the speed will be acceptable in many situations.

```
Do While Right(s, 1) = "-"
  s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is working. Performance is not an issue here.

Comment: If performance is not an issue, then OP wouldn't bother using `Right$` and `Left$` too.